Pywinauto can't find opened subwindow
I am using pywinauto to automate a few tests on a remote desktop. In order to access it, I am treating it like a regular window. I can click inside it and open the settings. Unfortunately I have run into a problem from there on. pywinauto cannot seem to find the settings that have been opened on the remote desktop.
This is what I have tried so far. The remote desktop is found and prints 'pass'. Settings always throws an error.
def open_run():
    dialog = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title='192.168.15.10 - Remotedesktopverbindung')
    if dialog.is_visible():
        print('pass')
    #click into the remote desktop
    dialog.click_input()
    #open the settings
    send_keys("{VK_LWIN down}r{VK_LWIN up}")
    send_keys("ms-settings:{ENTER}", with_spaces=True)
    test = dialog.child_window(title='Settings')
    if test.is_visible():
        print('pass')


Remote Desktop doesn't provide detailed info about any remote windows or widgets by design. It only translates the picture and receives basic input events from mouse and keyboard. Typical scenario to run something remotely is copying your script to remote machine and run there. Of course, you need to modify RDP settings or use VNC server software instead to prevent "diconnect/minimize RDP" problem which de-activates the active desktop as a default behavior. Some recipes are provided in the docs: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html
